# IICS and Oracle CLOB

Tags: oracle, informatica, clob, iics

*Question on IICS :*

1. Extracting data from a oracle CLOB datatype.
2. The CLOB field contains XML in it.
3. When extracting from Oracle using IICS, the source datatype is set to Text with the max field limit of 104857600.
4. **The data is truncating right at the source** (Noticed it at the transformation preview) at whatever datatype I get to use (text, next, nvarchar, varchar) .
5. The data will be loaded in Snowflake.

Any solution is greatly appreciated

Thanks,
B

Comment: What is the length of the source value?

Comment: Source is a oracle CLOB column. When I checked the length goes upto 112500. But it gets truncated at 47914